# Trying to output a filename through a one to many relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am getting the error

> call to a member function documents() on boolean

As I am trying to get the filename of the uploaded document for a card.  I have created a relationship between `Cards` and `CardDocuments`:

Cards.php:

```php
public function documents()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CardDocuments::class);
}
```

CardDocuments.php:

```php
public function files()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Card::class, 'card_id');
}
```

After doing that I used this in the view:

```php
@foreach ($cards as $card)
    {{ $card->documents()->filename }}
@endforeach
```

And the card_document migration:

```php
Schema::create('card_documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('card_id')->unsigned()->index();
    $table->foreign('card_id')->references('id')->on('cards');
    $table->string('filename')->nullable();
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Not sure why this is showing a boolean error as the file submission for this works and the files are saved successfully to the database so can't understand why I can't access `documents()` to get the filename to output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that documents are nested array:

```php
        @foreach ($cards as $card)
            @foreach ($card->documents as $document)
                {{ $document->filename }}
            @endforeach
        @endforeach
```